# vscode terminal file path showing double

Tags: terminal, visual-studio-code

I updated VS Code yesterday to 1.13 and now my terminal shows the filepath in the prompt twice. When I start typing the second instance disappears until I stop typing again - very annoying. Anyone else getting this or know how to fix it.

Using ZSH, oh-my-zsh, agnoster theme, meslo for powerline font.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are running into this bug: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/26038

This should already be fixed in the insider builds and the 1.13.1 recovery build should fix it as well

Comment: I answered this yesterday but the answer was incorrectly deleted as a duplicate of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44531775/vsc-icons-broken/44533296#44533296) by a moderator. They are different bugs

Comment: Fantastic, I updated to 1.13.1 and it solved it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem. Saw that there's a bug open in the VS Code repo for this: [Integrated Terminal show duplicate folder name #27941](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/27941)