# VSC Icons Broken

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a problem with icons, it's seems broken.

Did anyone have such a problem?

How to resolve it?

My VSC Version is **1.13.0.**

[image: VSC PROBLEM]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are running into this bug: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/28345

This should already be fixed in the [insider builds](https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders) and the 1.13.1 recovery build should fix it as well